# Get single value from dictionary by key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

```
var listaFirme = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "foo", "bar" }
};

var matchKey = "foo";

return listaFirme.Where(pair => pair.Key == matchKey).Select(pair => pair.Value).ToString();
```

I know that the keys are unique, so I want to return one value from my Dictionary. In this case it doesn't work, as it returns the string `"System.IEnumerable<String>"`...

Comment: `Select` returns an Ienumerable.  Perhaps you should add `FirstOrDefault` to the Select call.

Comment: As you have a dictionary, why aren't you using the methods specifically provided by dictionary, e.g. the indexer or `TryGetValue`? Your current approach loses all the performance benefits of using a dictionary at all...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It really does seem like you're overcomplicating this issue.

You can just use the indexer (`[]`) of the `Dictionary` class along with the `.ContainsKey()` method.

If you use something like this:

```
string value;
if (myDict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    value = myDict[key];
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key Not Present");
    return;
}
```

You should achieve the effect that you want.

Comment: Don't use the `ContainsKey` and `[]` pair. You are doubling the lookups that dictionary has to do. Use `TryGetValue` instead.

Comment: True, but if your dictionary isn't huge I prefer using this for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to retrieve a value of a key from a dictionary access by indexer or `TryGetValue`:

```
var value = listaFirme[matchKey];

//If you don't know for sure that dictionary contains key
string value;
if(a.TryGetValue(matchKey, out value))
{
    /* Code here */
}
```

As for why you got the result you did: Linq operations of `Where` and `Select` return an `IEnumerable<T>` so when doing `ToString` on it it executes the `ToString` of `IEnumerable` which is to print it's type.

*Notice that `listaFirme` isn't a good name for a `dictionary`*

---

If you did not have a dictionary and wanted to return one item then you'd use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var value = someList.FirstOrDefault(item => /* some predicate */)?.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you've overcomplicated the usage. In this case you don't need `Linq`.
Just use the `Dictionary` provided indexer: `listaFirme[matchKey]`. This returns the related value. IF the key does not exist the `Dictionary` throws a `KeyNotFoundException` exception. If you want to check if the key exists you can use the `ContainsKey()` method which returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `toString();` with `FirstOrDefault();`

When you are applying `.Where()` condition it will return an `Enumerable`. You have to either cast it to list using `.ToList()` then you will get list of the values that meet the condition you used, or if you just want to get the first one you can use `FirstOrDefault();`

You can also write it like this

```
listaFirme.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Key == matchKey).Value
```

Since `FirstOrDefault()` accepts a predicate, you don't need always need to use `.Where`.

Comment: I hope it is better now.

Comment: this is the best, easiest and one liner solution